# Firemonkey style designer make TRectangle fill parent

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-xe7, firemonkey-style

I am trying to add a `TRectangle` object to a Firemonkey control in the style designer to give the control a background color.  I can add the `TRectangle` and size it manually, however then the style does not work if the control changes size in the designer.  Is there a way I can make the `TRectangle` automatically take up the size of it's parent control?

Comment: what value you set in property TRectangle.Align? did you try with Align = Client?

Comment: Align = client did it!  I didn't even think to look at the align property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that property "TRectangle.Align" is set to "Client"